# Show picture in gallery in Xamarin.Forms Android API 29

Tags: c#, android, image, xamarin.forms, android-10.0

I created a sample for Xamarin.Forms (Android, iOS and UWP).

min version: Android 9.0 API 28

target version: Android 10.0 API 29

I use the nuget package "Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePad.Forms" to create a SignaturePad. This works but I dont see the saved picture in the gallery of my tablet (Tablet with Android 10.0 API 29)
But the image is under *com.sample\files\pictures*.

**Why the picture is not showing in the gallery of the tablet?**

**Get Image from SignaturePad**

```
 Stream signatureImage = await ((SignaturePad.Forms.SignaturePadView)pParameter).GetImageStreamAsync(SignaturePad.Forms.SignatureImageFormat.Png, Color.Black, Color.White);

 if (signatureImage != null)
 {
    DependencyService.Get<IMediaService>().SavePictureToDisk("currentSignature3.png",((MemoryStream) signatureImage).ToArray());
 }
```

**DpendencyService from Android**

```
public class MediaService : IMediaService
{
    Context CurrentContext => CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;

    public void SavePictureToDisk(string pFileName, byte[] pImageData)
    {           
        //"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.sample/files/Pictures/currentSignature3.png"
        var externalfilePath = CurrentContext.GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).AbsolutePath;           
        var filePath = Path.Combine(externalfilePath, pFileName);

        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, pImageData);

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {                
            MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile(CurrentContext, new String[] { filePath }, null, null);

            Console.WriteLine("File exists");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File error");
        }
    }      
}
```

MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile should add the picture to the gallery, or not?
I added all permissions, because the file is created.

Comment: Files in the ../Android/.. directories will not be scanned by the mediastore.

Comment: ok, then I need to copy the files to the other directories